# Python Nmap No Such File Or Directory

Tags: python, nmap

I'm trying to use nmap to scan for MAC addresses, but I can't get it to work. I installed nmap for Python2.7 from here: http://xael.org/norman/python/python-nmap/

Then I unzipped the file and ran

```
python setup.py install
```

Then I opened a session of python and tried this:

```
import nmap
nm = nmap.PortScanner()
```

But I get this error:

```
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: You probably need to install nmap itself onto your system and add it to you PATH so that it can be accessed by python-nmap. See http://nmap.org/

Comment: Hm nmap is installed already -- I'll try adding it to the PATH (have yet to figure out how to do that)

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Comment: I was using Raspbian for Raspberry Pi. I solved the issue by running sudo apt-get install nmap, instead of following the website's instructions.

Comment: You might want to add that in as the answer and mark it as accepted